# Where to ask questions related to image processing but have code?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I've already asked some questions which are related to image processing in the Signal Processing site which is logical for me and more specific to my problem, the problem is there is low view and answering rate there (compared to SO) plus I've encountered many questions related to image processing in SO, and apparently  moderators don't have any problem with it.

For me, I prefer to ask my question in the right place but in SO (it has more probability to be answered) plus, normally SO moderators will flag that kind of question as **out of subject**, yes it about code but there is specific site for that!

So, do I ask all the question which has code In SO no matter the subject is? or how?

PS: [Here is an example of one of my questions](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/59974/calculating-the-numerical-gradient-of-a-volume-in-one-direction-at-a-time)

Comment: In order for that question to qualify on Stack Overflow, you would have to also provide the expected output given a particular input, and the output you're actually getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the question you linked to would work well on SO as well. Any “how do I compute” question is welcome there, I’d say. If the question is more theoretical, ask it on Signal Processing SE.

Many sites in the SE network have overlap, some questions work well on multiple sites. However, don’t cross-post. Pick one site where you’d like to post the question.